# How do I join two tables in SQL to grab the names from one table and show them in a query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like this:

**Employee Table**:

| EmployeeID | firstName | lastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Johnny | Depp |
| 2 | Rebecca | Smith |
| 3 | Rodger | Doe |

**Sales Table**:

| EmployeeID | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100.20 |
| 2 | 200.19 |
| 3 | 355.23 |

And I'd like to join the tables to do something like this:

| EmployeeID | fullName | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Johnny Depp | 100.20 |
| 2 | Rebecca Smith | 200.19 |
| 3 | Rodger Doe | 355.23 |

How would I do that? Here's what I tried so far:

```
SELECT employee.firstName + employee.lastName AS fullName, employeeID, sales
FROM employee i 
INNER JOIN Sales s ON s.customerID = i.CustomerID
```

I'm getting a syntax error at my "+" symbol.

What's my problem?

Comment: Use the `concat()` functions, MySQL's way to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @Gordon said ,use `CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(employee.firstName, ' ', employee.lastName) AS fullName
       , employeeID
       , sales
FROM employee i 
INNER JOIN Sales s 
   ON s.customerID = i.CustomerID
```